# How to post a message on my Facebook wall?

Tags: android, facebook

All Facebook SDKs for Android require an "application key", which I assume is the API key for a facebook application that must be created on Facebook. Since all I want is to post to my wall without dealing with Facebook applications, is there an SDK for Android that doesn't require these api keys?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need API key anyway. It's free and you can get it right now. It's not actually a problem.
[Android/Java -- Post simple text to Facebook wall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953146/android-java-post-simple-text-to-facebook-wall/2956352#2956352)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Share Widget](http://www.facebook.com/share/) to post to Facebook wall without creating an application.