# Looking for android Facebook SDK examples

Tags: java, android, facebook, sdk, facebook-android-sdk

I've looked all over the internet and can't seem to find what i'm looking for...

I'm just trying to find a site with some examples on how to use the OFFICIAL facebook android SDK http://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

To be specific i'd like to see some examples on notification use and simple photo upload. But i'll take anything to help get a feel for using the SDK.

If anyone knows of any examples please share thank you so much!

Comment: I'm assuming you've already looked at http://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/examples/ and it doesn't have what you want?

Comment: Just added an answer with posting a photo from the handset.

Comment: Those samples aren't labelled, anyone know which one is for photo sharing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I asked a similar question a few weeks ago regarding the official Facebook Android SDK and posting content to one's wall ([Android/Java -- Post simple text to Facebook wall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953146/android-java-post-simple-text-to-facebook-wall)). That should help you get a feel for what it's like to post text to one's wall. I should point out though that you need to first create a Fackbook app and apply for an API key from Fackbook.com ([https://kunukd.com/](http://www.shoutmeloud.com/how-to-acquire-your-facebook-api-key.html))...if it asks about the platform of the app you intent to create, choose mobile.

You can modify the code in the Stack Overflow link I posted (above) to post photos too. At present though, according to the official git page for the Facebook Android SDK (under "Known Issues"):

> 3.Binary API parameters (such as uploading pictures) is not yet
>   supported -- coming soon...

So, while you can post a photo to your wall if you have the URL of the image file (the file must already be on the Internet), you can't use this SDK to send binary/byte data of the photo from the Android device (yet... as of 07/24/10). At least, that's what I gather from the statement above.

Replace the following lines of the sample code I posted in the other Stack Overflow post (link above):

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("message", "this is a test");// the message to post to the wall
facebookClient.dialog(this, "stream.publish", parameters, this);// "stream.publish" is an API call
```

with this

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("message", "Test Photo");
parameters.putString("attachment", "{\"name\":\"My Test Image\","
+"\"href\":\""+"http://www.google.com"+"\","
+"\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\""+"http://www.google.com/logos/mucha10-hp.jpg"+"\",\"href\":\""+"http://www.google.com"+"\"}]"
+"}");
facebookClient.dialog(this, "stream.publish", parameters, this);
```

and you should be able to post photos to your wall (as well as text and links).

For more help on structuring the "attachment" string, go here: http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/android/845/.

Other than that, consider using a third-party package or wait for the official SDK to be updated if you need to post photos to an album directly from the device.

Comment: That will definitely help so much! Thanks you! And also im curious if you might know the answer to this, Does the SDk maybe have like a "Notifications" class that maybe i could just reference to with a status bar notification and get it to check say like if messages > 1 blah blah. Sorry im really new to this. But this has all been really helpful

Comment: How stupid. I thought I can pack attachment into another bundle and make parameters.putBundle(attachmentBundle); But that leads to NullPointerException in the Util.encodeUrl(Bundle parameters) I recommend to use http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html instead.

Comment: Great work boy....Really awesome.....thanks a lot....

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
byte[] data = null;
try {
    ContentResolver cr = mainActivity.getContentResolver();
    InputStream fis = cr.openInputStream(localSnapshotUri);
    Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    data = baos.toByteArray();              
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}     

Bundle params = new Bundle(); 
params.putString("method", "photos.upload");          
params.putByteArray("picture", data);

AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener());
```

Parameters used here are:

- `localSnapshotUri` which points to some image in you /sdcard/.. or wherever it is :)
- `mainActivity` that is app main activity
- `SampleUploadListener` an implemetation of `AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener` interface

Have a nice programming!

Comment: Thanks. Will this still upload even if the application has been closed?

Answer (score 2):

Just posted here the simple way to upload a photo:

[android facebook publish photo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647767/android-facebook-publish-photo)

Code:

```
byte[] data = null;

Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoToPost);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
data = baos.toByteArray();

Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
params.putByteArray("picture", data);

AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);
```

Comment: what is SampleUploadListener() ?

Comment: Part of the example provided by the Facebook SDK.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I got it. But while i am using your code it simple said that, Host is unresolved.

Comment: It is probably best to ask a new question and show the code you are using. There needs to be more detail in order to know what you are doing.

Comment: please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065116/why-my-code-not-work-to-upload-the-photo-on-facebook-from-in-android

Comment: I have post the Question on the Stackoverflow. So please help me for it.

Comment: "picture" is for sharing the image urls.

Answer (score 1):

By far the easiest and working example of posting to user's wall without the dialog once logged on, and using the new Facebook SDK, is:
http://www.integratingstuff.com/2010/10/14/integrating-facebook-into-an-android-application/

By the way, posting images is done with:

```
parameters.putString("picture", "http://www.google.com/logos/mucha10-hp.jpg");
```

Comment: It works but gives exception about expecting byte array instead of url of the image.