# Why my code not work to upload the Photo on Facebook from in android?

Tags: android, facebook

I have integrated the Facebook-sdk successfully in to my appplication.
Now i am going to share a photo to Facebook. To do that I am using this code:

```
facebook.authorize(DrawingActivity.this, new String[]{ "user_photos,publish_checkins,publish_actions,publish_stream"},new DialogListener() {                     
                @Override                     
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}                      
                @Override                     
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}                      
                @Override                     
                public void onError(DialogError e) {}                      
                @Override                     
                public void onCancel() {}                 
            }); 


            byte[] data = null;  Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(APP_FILE_PATH + "/myAwesomeDrawing.png"); 
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
            bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); 
            data = baos.toByteArray();  
            Bundle params = new Bundle(); 
            params.putString("method", "photos.upload"); 
            params.putByteArray("picture", data);  
            AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook); 
            mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);
```

and another code is:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

public class SampleUploadListener extends BaseRequestListener {      
    public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {         
        try {             
            // process the response here: (executed in background thread)             
            Log.d("Facebook-Example", "Response: " + response.toString());             
            JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);             
            final String src = json.getString("src");              
            // then post the processed result back to the UI thread             
            // if we do not do this, an runtime exception will be generated             
            // e.g. "CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original             
            // thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."          
        } catch (JSONException e) {             
            Log.w("Facebook-Example", "JSON Error in response");         
        } catch (FacebookError e) {             
            Log.w("Facebook-Example", "Facebook Error: " + e.getMessage());         
        }     
    }      
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {         
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    } 
}
```

Now, I dont know why i am not able to get upload photo on the facebook?

Comment: @alextsc: I am not able to post the photo. But while second time while i click on facebook Button it will post the photo.

Comment: Hi all can some one tell me why am getting error in this line "facebook.authorize(DrawingActivity.this, new String[]{ "user_photos,publish_checkins,publish_actions,publish_stream"},new DialogListener() {" even after importing the android facebook sdk???

Comment: @android_murali: Please put the question on stack and give link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do, you need to give a target (first null) to this line of code:

```
mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);
```

For example, if you're trying to make a post on the current users wall, it should look like:

```
mAsyncRunner.request("me/posts", params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);
```

You will need the correct permissions to do this: at least publish_stream.

See [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts)

Comment: Ok then What should i have to write ? "me/posts" or "me" or "posts" ??

Comment: Still i am not able to Post the Photo first time. But while second time while i pressed the fecebook button. it will post the photo.