# Post Photo to Facebook from Android Application, Photo taken from Android Gallery

Tags: android, facebook, post, image

I am currently developing an Android Application target build is 4.0 Ice-Cream Sandwich.

So far, I am able to post a normal Text onto Facebook with this code:

```
public void postToWall() {

      // post on user's wall.

        facebook.dialog(this, "feed", new DialogListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(DialogError e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
    }
        });

}
```

However, I am unable to post a photo onto Facebook with Captions. I've search around online and one of the codes I found is this:

```
public void postToWall() {
        // post on user's wall.
        byte[] data = null;

        Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoToPost);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        data = baos.toByteArray();

        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
        params.putByteArray("picture", data);

        AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
        mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);

    }
```

The problem is, the above code is not working as I don't know whats:

1.*photoToPost*

2.*mAsyncRunner*.request keeps giving me an error stating that I cannot put "null" as it is an invalid arguement

3.*SampleUploadListener*, supposedly is from the FacebookSDK is not working as well (I keep getting an error to create a Class)

Is there a simpler code out here ? Or could someone explain to me the errors I am experiencing.

I am using an "On Click" so far to post normal Text onto Facebook and it points to this method. My goal is to upload a Photo with a Caption onto Facebook.

Thank you all for helping !

Comment: Did you see all the related question on the right? 
**1**. is the File object of your image. You can search get image from gallery.
**2**. Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8065344/1050058)

Answer (score 0):

See this [link](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-facebook-integration/). That will show you how to post image on FaceBook wall as how to post text on wall.

Its good to learn.

Comment: Please extract the essential upload image part. This answer will helpless in case referenced site is down.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for the link. I saw the code and it posts Image to Facebook wall based on an image that is already uploaded (the code gets the Image by URL). Although this is not what I'm looking for, I learn alot from it also. Thank you !

Comment: ok. so you want on upload photo from sd card or something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

1-This is your photo that will be send to wall , it can be an image from your SD card or anywhere else

2-This a class from Facebook SDK , that accepts facebook object (one u created before)

3-This a class from Facebook SDK again

it seems there is something wrong with your Facebook SDK
try to set it again using Right Click on Project >> Properties >> Android and see if library exist or not

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for the reply ! I will check again and get back to you !

Comment: 1- So can I create a String Variable to hold the image ? 

For the rest, I manage to get the class code but I am still getting an error for mAsyncRunner.request("me/feed", params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);

The error is as follow:
The method request(String,Bundle,String,AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener, Object) in the type AsyncFacebooKRunner isn ot applicable for the arguments (String,Bundle,String,MainActivity.SampleUploadListener,null);

Comment: 1-no you can not put image into the string variable ! this is what i am talking about , you can just put image's URL into String not the whole file, you need to decode it by Bitmap class

Comment: OH !!! Ok ok. I managed to get it up by posting an image from my R.drawable. Now I'm trying to post an image from the gallery (users should be prompted to select an image from the phone's gallery to be uploaded onto Facebook). 

I shall post another question about that. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in following line

```
mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);
```

you are passing null as graph path this should be like this = "me/feed"

**Update**
 write this line of code

```
mAsyncRunner.request("me/feed", params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);
```

then it should work.

Comment: Hmm I'm still quite confused with the "me/feed". Is it possible to explain it a little more ? Programming is still new to me... Thanks for the fast reply ! :)

Comment: you just write this line instead of that

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CardShared extends Activity{

public static final String APP_ID = "YOUR APP ID";
private Facebook mFacebook;
private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner ;
boolean isLoggedIn = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mFacebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);

    //Implementing SSO
    mFacebook.authorize(this, new String[]{"publish_stream"}, new DialogListener(){

        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

            sharePicture(values.getString(Facebook.TOKEN));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Picture Shared Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            CardShared.this.finish();
        }


        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
            Log.d("FACEBOOK ERROR","FB ERROR. MSG: "+e.getMessage()+", CAUSE: "+e.getCause());
        }


        public void onError(DialogError e) {
            Log.e("ERROR","AUTH ERROR. MSG: "+e.getMessage()+", CAUSE: "+e.getCause());
        }


        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d("CANCELLED","AUTH CANCELLED");
        }
    });
}

//updating Status
public void sharePicture(String accessToken){

    byte[] data = null;
    try {
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image_to_be_uploaded);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        data = baos.toByteArray();

        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
        params
                .putString(Facebook.TOKEN, mFacebook
                        .getAccessToken());
        params.putByteArray("picture", data);
        mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST",
                new SampleUploadListener(), null);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Log.d("onActivityResult","onActivityResult");
    mFacebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
public class SampleUploadListener extends BaseRequestListener {

    public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
        try {

            Log.d("Facebook-Example", "Response: " + response.toString());
            JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
            final String f = json.getString("src");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.w("Facebook-Example", "JSON Error in response");
        } catch (FacebookError e) {
            Log.w("Facebook-Example", "Facebook Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi ! Thanks also for the fast response. I will try it out and let you know on my progress again ! (I'm a high school student so Programming is still kind of new to me).

Comment: Hi I'm getting a Null Exception error at this line image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);

I am not sure what to do with photoToPost. I declared it as a String. I am quite sure it is empty but how do I fill it up with the photo from the Android Gallery ? Please help ! THanks !

Comment: I am also not sure on where to put the Method to share, it keeps getting bracket errors. Do you have a sample class with all the methods to show please ?

Comment: Now see my edited answer, it is a complete class. U just need to intent here, may be from a button click or "Upload". And now u can see, bitmap image is the image saved in your drawable folder, this image will be uploaded. you have to provide the bitmap of the image that u want to upload on facebook

Answer (score 0):

put like this

```
mAsyncRunner.request("me/feed", params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener())
```