# Facebook/Twitter Integration in my android application

Tags: android

I want to integrate Facebook/Twitter apps in my Android project. On click of Facebook button after simple login procedure the image or text I want to share on Facebook. The same I want to repeat for Twitter.

I tried the code from https://github.com/Facebook/Facebook-Android-sdk/tree/master/examples/simple but that never work for me.
Please help me & provide me some sample appication for this.

Comment: What kind of problems are you having? Can get be specific? Please read [ask] to learn how to get better responses. The Facebook Android SDK sample application would, in my opinion, be the best sample application to start from :>.

Comment: you want to use the current sample and solve the problem or need another sample (to solve post your problem and to find more there are alreayd QA on SO for that...and also can search for)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for android Facebook SDK examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323496/looking-for-android-facebook-sdk-examples)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook integration is one of those tedious tasks.For this i searched each & every link available on net.

After the 2 weeks i found the solution.By this you can integrate facebook in your app as well as share some text on your wall.It is really easy to do.
I have given you a link that will help you to do that http://www.android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/290-facebook-integration-in-your-android-application
By that link you can easily do that. 
Thanks to everyone who helped me. I expect the same support from all of you in future as well.

Also you can do this by the Facebook SDK https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/. It is easy to use and the example code you can find from  this link https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

Comment: what about image sharing in twitter? @naresh sharma