# Unable to implement Facebook Integration in Android

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to implement the Facebook implementation as mentioned in the following link -

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/

However, after I've implemented upto step 6.3 and try to run my application, I'm being shown the following error message in the log -

```
03-01 14:19:50.124: W/dalvikvm(329): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
03-01 14:19:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(329): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
03-01 14:19:50.173: E/AndroidRuntime(329): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.android.Facebook
03-01 14:19:50.173: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at com.test.fbandroid.MyGreatAppActivity.<init>(MyGreatAppActivity.java:14)
03-01 14:19:50.173: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-01 14:19:50.173: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1479)
03-01 14:19:50.173: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
03-01 14:19:50.173: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2409)
03-01 14:19:50.173: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
03-01 14:19:50.173: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
03-01 14:19:50.173: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
03-01 14:19:50.173: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-01 14:19:50.173: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-01 14:19:50.173: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
03-01 14:19:50.173: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-01 14:19:50.173: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-01 14:19:50.173: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
03-01 14:19:50.173: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-01 14:19:50.173: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm using Android 2.1 with version 7 as the mini SDK.
Any pointers on this would be of great help.

Thanks in advance,
Amitava

Comment: Have you try to run the demo application (Hackbook) that comes in the downloaded bundle.

Comment: It is easy to implement check the link below
[facebook integration][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162451/facebook-twitter-integration-in-my-android-application

Answer (score 1):

it's quite easy ....

Download the code for [facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk)  and add as a  library in your project and then run it.

Add two variables as

```
String appId="000000000000000"; //your appp ID
Facebook facebook;
```

and initialise the `facebook` variable

```
facebook = new Facebook(appId);
```

Comment: Hi, I downloaded the facebook SDK from github, linked it to my application as a library, and tried to run my application by creating the application ID and instance of Facebook. But I'm being shown the following error - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.android.Facebook

Comment: please add facebook sdk as a reference (library) from the  android section under property window and test it ...

Comment: Hi, I have completed upto step 6.4 mentioned in the following URL - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/ but still I'm facing the NoClassDefFoundError for the Facebook class. Any pointers on this would be really helpful. I'm using Android 2.2 in my emulator. Thanks in advance,Amitava