# how to send image on twitter in android

Tags: android, image, twitter

i m new in android i try to send the image in twitter , i use this but is not help full http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-send-image-to-twitpic-from-android/ and i also use this [Android Intent for Twitter application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077008/android-intent-for-twitter-application/9151983?noredirect=1#comment22129355_9151983) not get success can any budy share with me .. code please help me friends

Comment: Check this below link this one be Useful For You

[Twitter and Facebook Integration][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162451/facebook-twitter-integration-in-my-android-application/

Answer (score 2):

you can use twitter4j library for android

http://twitter4j.org/en/

its easy to use

```
StatusUpdate status = new StatusUpdate(message);
    status.setMedia(file); // image location
    twitter.updateStatus(status);
```