# Webview in Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, webview, scroll

I'm trying to integrate some Facebook stuff (posting on your own "wall") in my TabView.
The problem I'm facing is that while I do not have the Facebook app installed, I get a Webview showing the login and posting. It shows nicely, except for the buttons at the bottom. If I scroll down to see the buttons, they just go a little bit lower.

The layout of the tab:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="40dip">
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Test_Facebook_Layout">
      <Button android:id="@+id/facebookButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login to facebook"/>
 </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Got all the code (except the parts I changed and will post below) from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953146/android-java-post-simple-text-to-facebook-wall).

```
    public void onClick(View v)
{
    if (v == facebookButton)
    {
        facebookClient = new Facebook("myAwesomeKey");
        facebookClient.authorize(this, new String[] {"publish_stream", "read_stream", "offline_access"}, this);
    }
}

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953146/android-java-post-simple-text-to-facebook-wall
    setContentView(R.layout.detailsfacebooktab);

    facebookButton = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.facebookButton);
    facebookButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

What would be nice is either a) Getting the WebView to not fill my screen or b) Keep the buttons from scrolling away.

EDIT: Because a picture says more than a thousend words, here's three thousand words.
(if it isn't clear, Picture 1 shows the initial view, Picture 2 shows my scrolling down, Picture 3 shows the buttons getting away)

[image]
[image]
[image]

For the moment I found a c) Getting the buttons a bit higher.
The problem is the user can still scroll the WebView, enlarging the View and scrolling the buttons back down again.

I edited these values in `com.facebook.android.fbDialog.java` to show the buttons a bit more.

```
static final float[] DIMENSIONS_LANDSCAPE = {440, 260};
static final float[] DIMENSIONS_PORTRAIT = {280, 380};
```

Because this does not completely solve my problem, I've edited my OP instead of posting my own "answer".

Thank you,

iarwain01