# Androids Facebook SDK, single sign on question?

Tags: android, facebook

On Androids Facebook SDK there is a single login feature which I can't get to work.
Done all the key hash thing but maybe there is something wrong with this method.
What exactly should I pass on, or could somebody explain what this is supposed to do?

`@Override`

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook Single Sign On works fine, but the documentation is not all that great. Get your class to override the Facebook DialogListener.

To request Single Sign On, make sure you're calling Facebook to authorize your app -

```
 facebookClient = new Facebook(FB_APP_ID);

        facebookClient.authorize(this, 
            new String[] {"publish_stream", "read_stream", "offline_access"}, this);
```

And you also need to override the OnComplete method. Your OnActivityResult method is absolutely fine.

I used the code given by this gentleman [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953146), and it worked perfectly fine for me, except that some of the code that he'd written was using the old API, so you might need to change some parameters passed to methods.

Comment: The link given works for posting to facebook. But its not really supporting single sign on

Answer (score -1):

I don't think single sign on could work well in the Facebook Android SDK.
       In the method  private boolean startSingleSignOn(Activity activity, String applicationId,String[] permissions, int activityCode){} ,you will see below

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana",
                "com.facebook.katana.ProxyAuth");

 try {
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, activityCode);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        didSucceed = false;
    }
```

In fact, package com.facebook.katana doesn't exist in the Facebook Android SDK.so the method  private boolean startSingleSignOn(Activity activity, String applicationId,
            String[] permissions, int activityCode){} will return false ,then it means that single sign-on is Not available.

Comment: That's because com.facebook.katana is part of the closed official facebook app.

Comment: i know that, just give your answers,please.

Answer (score -1):

**facebookClient.authorize**
This method doesn't work on my device until I renamed those parameters:
**"com.facebook.katana","com.facebook.katana.ProxyAuth"**
to 
**"com.facebook.katana1","com.facebook.katana.ProxyAuth1"**
=(