# facebook implementation in android

Tags: android

I am developing android application which involves implementation of facebook.I have found one example listed on 
http://www.androidpeople.com/android-facebook-api-example-using-fbrocket/
It is running fine.But when i delete libraries from the code it gives error.Can anyone give me example

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Answer (score 0):

The best link for me was:
http://integratingstuff.com/category/web-services/facebook/

It uses the official Facebook SDK from facebook for Android and works really great.
remember to try it on an emulator since the device will be looking for a single logon from facebook from your phone, and for that to work you have to register a key-hash in your application on Facebook (which is clearly explained in the official Facebook SDK for Android.

Other links that might be helpful:
http://www.shoutmeloud.com/how-to-acquire-your-facebook-api-key.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953146/android-java-post-simple-text-to-facebook-wall