# Post on facebook wall  in android?

Tags: android

In the Android **Gallery** in the phone there is an option to share the image to **facebook and post it on the wall**.I want to **post a message or an image on to the wall in the exactly similar way** from my app.How can this be done?

**My understanding**:I believe that it uses facebook  app already present in my phone.If that's the case then i can start that particular  activity or throw an intent corresponding to that activity from my app.If this is the case can someone let me know what is the  **corresponding intent** that i should be throwing.**What are the parameters that i should be passing in the intent and under what keyname should i pass these parameters?**

Correct me if my understanding is wrong and let me know how this can be done.

**P.S**:I have been using the facebook sdk according to this wonderful post [Android/Java -- Post simple text to Facebook wall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953146/android-java-post-simple-text-to-facebook-wall) and it works.But the dialogs don't look that good.That's why i am looking for a different option.

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'the dialogs don't look good'? That way any new solution can overcome these limits as you see them.

Comment: I believe it is shown on a web view and is very congested and the one i had seen in the gallery looks way better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the ACTION_SEND intent.

See [this post](http://labs.emich.be/2010/01/23/how-to-send-to-twitter-or-facebook-from-your-android-application/).

Edit: and [its doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND)

Second edit: note that if the guy does not have the Facebook app, he won't be able to share. If you use [the Facebook API](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/), then he will be able to share to facebook, but facebook only.

Comment: Yes this was what i was looking for but seems like the ACTION_SEND intent is not handled properly by facebook now.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515198/share-text-on-facebook-from-android-app-via-action-send

Comment: ACTION_SEND is not handled properly but it still works for basic use.  What is broken is that it doesn't handle all of the fields in ACTION_SEND and doesn't use the facebook app to handle the action.  Instead it opens a webpage to m.facebook.com to handle the wall post (at least it authenticates).

Answer (score 1):

For a long time research. Finally i found out the solution..

it's works for me very well.

```
private void postToFacebookViaIntent() {
File mFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/images.jpg");
    Intent shareIntent = findFacebookClient();

    if (shareIntent != null &&  mFile!= null) {

        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(mFile)); 
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share"));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(SharingActivity.this, "Facebook App is not installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

}

```
private Intent findFacebookClient() {
    final String twitterApps = "facebook";
    Intent facebookIntent = new Intent();
    facebookIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    facebookIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(
            facebookIntent, 0);

    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : list) {
        String p = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
        if (p != null && p.contains(twitterApps)) {
            facebookIntent.setPackage(p);
            return facebookIntent;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This article can help you solver this problem. 
http://vnstep.wordpress.com/2012/04/14/share-via-android/ or
[Share Text on Facebook from Android App via ACTION_SEND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515198/share-text-on-facebook-from-android-app-via-action-send)