# facebook.authorize not working on mobile phone

Tags: android

facebook.authorize(this,new String[] { "email", "read_stream" },new DialogListener() 
giving me problem on mobile phone... but its working on Emulator..
can anyone tell me what idone wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

..take a look at my post from the other week 
[found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960224/post-to-user-facebook-wall-not-working-when-facebook-app-is-installed-on-device-e)

I found that the best way to get facebook integrated with your app is to look at the examples at github.

Comment: U r right about login session but in authorize i make some changes and its working fine for me  facebook.authorize(this,PERMISSIONS, facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new DialogListener()

Answer (score 3):

Did you add this function? If not, just add it.

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
 {  
   facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 }
```