# Android Facebook post does not work when the Facebook app is already installed on the device

Tags: android, facebook, device

I have an app that posts a string to user's wall. The app worked ok in the emulator but I could not make it work in a real device. At first I thought I have a problem with the hash key. But then I tried it on a device that does not have Fb installed on it and it worked. When I installed Fb on the device it did not post and uninstalling it again it works fine. I assume that the Facebook app is blocking my app from using the SDK? The approach I use is more or less following this -> http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/28/30-minute-guide-integrating-facebook-android-application/
but I get the same with other approaches.

I see that there is a problem reading this -> [Post to user facebook wall not working when Facebook app is installed on device/emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960224/post-to-user-facebook-wall-not-working-when-facebook-app-is-installed-on-device) 
but what should I do to solve it? I do not want my users to have to uninstall Fb of course! Has anyone come to the same situation and managed to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Small Changes in the code (facebook package)

Look into `authorize` function in `facebook.java` file. try to `comment` out the `singlesignon` and use startdialog() only... something like this.. hope it helps.

Comment: Yo mean that this code:
        // Prefer single sign-on, where available.
        
if (activityCode >= 0) {

            singleSignOnStarted = startSingleSignOn(activity, 

mAppId,

                    permissions, activityCode);

        }

        // Otherwise fall back to traditional dialog.

        if (!singleSignOnStarted) {

            startDialogAuth(activity, permissions);

        }

should be changed to just this ->
startDialogAuth(activity, permissions);
so that SSO will be disabled?

Comment: in the com.facebook.android comment startSingleSignOn() fuction and startDialogAuth(activity, permissions); enable. (don't comment this line.

Comment: I had some authentication problems, but now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem and I had to disable SSO to enable it to work.

Answer (score 0):

above answer given by Raja is perfect..

this is what i did and worked perfectly...
earlier i found difficult to understand what to do exactly...

so this is what i did...
hope this may help others

```
// Prefer single sign-on, where available.
//      if (activityCode >= 0) {
//          singleSignOnStarted = startSingleSignOn(activity, mAppId,
//                  permissions, activityCode);
//      }
// Otherwise fall back to traditional dialog.
```