# Process for XAuth login through Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, xauth

I have a valid API key from facebook and I tried using this line of code:

```
facebookClient = new Facebook("my APP ID");
facebookClient.authorize(this, this)
```

from [Facebook login through android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547466/facebook-login-through-android)

I also overriden DialogListener in this class

```
@Override
public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
    System.out.println("TEST completed "+values);
}

@Override
public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
    System.out.println("TEST error: "+e.getMessage());
}

@Override
public void onError(DialogError e) {
    System.out.println("TEST error: "+e.getMessage());
}

@Override
public void onCancel() {
    System.out.println("TEST cancelled!");
}
```

But logcat does not print any message from the implemented methods.

Is there something that I have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one is answering and I just found my fix.

For my solution, I had to make sure that I was logged in facebook.

```
if (Session.getActiveSession() != null) {
  //implement dialog listener
} else {
  //do facebook login here
}
```