# Add Facebook API to existing Android project

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook

I'm trying to add Facebook funcionality to my Android game and I can't figure out how to properly get the Facebook SDK to work.

I followed the instructions on the Facebook Developers site, created the hash keys and release keys and all that stuff, but when it comes to getting the code in eclipse to work I keep running into errors all over the place.

FB suggests adding the Facebook SDK project into eclipse and that works fine, except it just sits there as a separate project and I can't get my code to use it.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953146/android-java-post-simple-text-to-facebook-wall) that suggests adding the com folder of the FB Sdk to your project - but that just creates a cascade of other errors (most seem to relate to the files not finding com.facebook.android.R, and others import errors )

I keep looking around and every post I find either suggests the same things I've already tried or assumes you already got the sdk integrated without a hitch...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a litle research, it seems if your project and the FB SDK library are in different drive letters (whether partitions or different drives altogether), importing the library will fail.

Moving the FB SDK to the same drive fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear whether you did this or not, to use the facebook sdk:

1. Import the Facebook SDK project to eclipse
2. Make sure both your project and the facebook sdk are open
3. Right click your project -> Properties -> Android. In the library section, click Add and find the Facebook SDK

If that still doesn't work, make sure you're using the latest facebook sdk and android sdk

Comment: Did that and I'm using the latest SDK.

Comment: Actually, I'm checking now. I can add the SDK as a library to my project and it shows a green check mark and everything looks fine, but if I open the properties again to double check, the SDK shows a red x mark and the project name shows as "?"

Comment: Well there's your problem, though I'm not sure what could be causing that. Maybe it's a bug in Eclipse? try following the path it displays under 'Reference' in the library list and see if that's where it should be

Comment: I had some trouble trying to reference the SDK when it's not on the same hard-drive (Windows 8, Eclipse Juno)