# Why I am not able to post in facebook id using my android code

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am able to get profile information from facebook but not able to post somehing.
I also declared Internet permission in menifest file.

```
public void postToWall() {
        // post on user's wall.
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("message", "Hello");

    mAsyncRunner.request("feed", params, new RequestListener() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                Object state) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {

        }
    });
    }
```

This is my method to post something in user's wall

Comment: try "me/feed" instead of "feed"

Comment: @mayuri already tried it

Comment: you can also use this facebook.request("me/feed",params, "Post");

Comment: @mayuri still not working

Comment: http://pastie.org/8563214

Comment: @mayuri Thnx a lot, I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

Try read the documentation. Have a lot o code and explain how to do that.

[Documentation Facebook - Publish to Feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/publish-to-feed/)

Or try to search more on stackoverflow

[Post Simple Text on Facebook Wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953146/android-java-post-simple-text-to-facebook-wall)

I hope this help!